# How to create a UDF in HIVE using python for a Timestamp transformation

Tags: python, hive, timestamp, user-defined-functions, user-defined-data-types

I have a table which has the timestamp as below

```
DataFeedDTTM
------------
2016-10-20 15:57:42.1
```

But when I query it I need the format as below.

```
select DataFeedDTTM from atable;
```

(Data can be huge and hence need a optimal solution as well, but then I'm fine to have any inputs)

```
DataFeedDTTM
------------
20170209 12:14:54.100000
```

I have an alternative to do a Case When - Type casting. But then it doesn't seem to be simple.

The reason for it to be simple is, I have to dynamically for this query through a Python code and read the data from Hive and write it into a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

'datetime' module might help your task.

```
from datetime import datetime
d_in = "2016-10-20 15:57:42.1"
d = datetime.strptime("2016-10-20 15:57:42.1", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
d_out = d.strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
print(d_out)
```

This produces:

```
'20161020 15:57:42.100000'
```